# Profile tool in shell script cannot use > or >> when it is executed by Python

Tags: python, performance, shell, perf

I use perf to analyze code profiles in WSL2(a Linux subsystem).
I put the perf command in a shell script and use > or >> to store the profile info.

I find I when I use Python to execute such a shell script, no profile info could be written in the log file after > or >>.

It works well we I directly use the shell script.

I have tried os.system('command'), os.popen('command'),and the package subprocess.

shell script codes here:

```
clear 
make clean
make
perf stat ./a.out >> log_perf_stat.log
perf record -F 9999 ./a.out
perf report >> log_perf_report.log
perf annotate >> log_perf_annotate.log
```

Comment: What error messages does the sub-shell print?  Or if you run it under `strace -f -e file python ...`, what error return from an `open()` system call do you eventually get?  Probably something about permissions, either on an existing file, or for creating a new file in that directory?

Comment: Thank you very much, I think it is the permissions.